# Що таке «иносе»?

Tags: значення-слів, етимологія

Бачив кілька разів на Словотворі, що схвалюючи відповідник люди пишуть *Иносе!* Що це означає? Знайшов лиш оце:

> **Хорошо́** = **1.** хороше́, га́рно, гара́зд, до́бре, ле́псько, доладу́, кра́сно, фа́йно (Гал.). — Гарно грає, ще краще сьпіває. н. п. — Гарно твоя кобза, грає, любий мій земляче! Аф. — Добре роби, добре й буде. н. пр. — Було добре, та давно, а буде гаразд, та не зараз. н. пр. — Сьвятий спокою — гаразд з тобою. н. пр. — Ой не гаразд Запорожцї, не гаразд зробили. н. п. **2.** до́бре, гара́зд, сїлькі́сь (С. З.), **и́носе**. — Ну, добре, нехай буде, як ти кажеш. — Та приводь же хлопця ранїш. **Иносе**.

Схоже, що це слово синонім до *добре*, чи це так? Звідки воно?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> <sup>Етимологічний словник української мови Інституту мовознавства ім. О.О. Потебні НАН України.</sup>
>
> [ІНО́СЕ](//goroh.pp.ua/%D0%95%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%96%D1%8F/%D1%96%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B5) «хай так, гаразд, згоден»
>
> - очевидно, результат злиття прислівника [*іно́*] «лише, тільки» і займенника *се* «це»;
> - розвиток значення неясний;
> - Етимолоґічні відповідники: російська [*и́но́сь*] «тс.»;
> - Фонетичні та словотвірні варіанти: *ино́се*, *ино́си* «тс.», *іно́сь*.